# Rotating app shouldn't refresh data

Tags: feature-request, status-norepro, android-app, page-load

Pretty simple. When you rotate the screen on the mobile app, the data gets reloaded from the server. This can cause issues on slow connections. Also, it means that any expanded comments get unexpanded and have to be reloaded manually.

Please don't reload the data every time

Comment: It's a little tricky to get this working from my experience. See: [Don't reload application when orientation changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913130/dont-reload-application-when-orientation-changes) and [Activity restart on rotation Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456211/activity-restart-on-rotation-android?lq=1)

Comment: Where are you seeing a data reload? I'm not seeing this in either the feed or the Question/Answer view, it's redoing the layout of the page yes, but I don't see it making a network call anywhere.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi ...You might be right. I think I made the assumption that it was reloading based on the fact that rotating recollapses the comments, but more importantly, that it crashes the app if there's no data connection, just like a refresh does. But upon further testing, it appears difficult to tell if any data is actually refreshed. Should I edit this question to reflect the symptoms, instead of (what I thought was) the underlying issue? (Or tag it [meta-tag:status-norepro] it and I can ask another?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marked it as no repro per discussions in comment thread, please make a new question regarding the other issue you have.

Thanks!